# Ubuntu 13.10 and 12.04.4 installer not seeing partitions

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 64 bit on a Lenovo G500s machine. I have tried installing both 13.10 and 12.04.4 and I am having the same problem with both versions.

When I get to the installation process in the Ubuntu menu, The hard drive is seen as completely unallocated. I have partitioned the hard drive using Windows partition manager.

I would include a screen shot, but apparently I can't b/c I am new to the forums.

So, Windows partition manager sees the drive as follows,

```
Disk 0 - 931.51 GB
System Reserved 100 MB NTFS (Healthy, Primary Partition)
C:) 488.18 GB NTFS (Healthy, Primary Partition)
Unallocated 443.23 GB.
```

When in the Ubuntu installer, I ran `sudo fdisk -l` and this was the output.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical /physical) : 512 bytes / 4098 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes/ 4096 bytes
Disk identifier:  0xc0bbb31d

Device Boot    Start         End              Blocks      Id         System
/dev/sda1   *    2048      206847            102400        7     HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda 2       206848    1024002047    511897600    7     HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Any fixes that people can recommend to get the Ubuntu installer to see my partitions would be greatly appreciated!

I am happy to answer any questions!

Answer (score 0):

```
Device Boot    Start         End              Blocks      Id         System
/dev/sda1   *    2048      206847            102400        7     HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda 2       206848    1024002047         511897600    7     HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

It clearly shows that your disk has only two parttions.Both are formatted into ntfs filesystem. I recommend you to create a new ext4 partition for installing Ubuntu through gparted partition Editor.

After creating the new partition, install Ubuntu on it by choosing **something else** option.